# How do I set a breakpoint in based on a registry key being read?

Tags: .net, debugging, registry, breakpoints

I have an executable that uses a mix of managed and unmanaged code. I don't have the source code to it, but I can decompile it.

What I do know is at some point it reads a registry key, and then afterwards loads a manged DLL based on the assembly name in the registry. So I'd like to set a break point on that registry key being read, regardless of if its read in managed code or unmanaged code, and then look at the (hopefully managed) stacktrace. My plan then would be to use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to step through the decompiled code starting there, and watch the DLL in question get used.

Is this possible through the Visual Studio debugger, windbg or another debugger? I'm not that comfortable with WinDbg, but if I gotta use it, I will.

Answer (score 0):

I'm halfway there. Its possible to debug the Win32 API Functions via [a special syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d16ayc6z.aspx).

```
{,,FOO.DLL}_FunctionName@N
```

Unless its a 64 bit DLL in which case there is no decoration:

```
{,,FOO.DLL}FunctionName
```

My process is 32 bits. I've been unable to get a list of function decorations using any of the following:

- `dumpbin /exports c:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll`
- [This long blog article that seems to have some holes in it](http://entrian.com/blog/setting-a-visual-studio-breakpoint-on-a-win32-api-function-in-user32dll/)
- [This MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x49w699.aspx)

I believe this is due to SxS loading the wrong version of the dll.

However, [this post on Zach Burlingame's blog](http://www.zachburlingame.com/2011/09/setting-a-debug-breakpoint-in-a-win32-api-in-visual-studio/#comment-6398) enumerates the registry keys.

The breakpoint I need to set is {,,Advapi32.dll}_RegOpenKeyExW@20.

Now I need to make the breakpoint conditional on the registry path.

Answer (score 0):

windbg:

check symbols:

```
x advapi32!RegOpenKeyExW
```

If there is no problem with symbols, set breakpoint:

```
bp advapi32!RegOpenKeyExW
```

If windbg does not see symbols, try:

```
.symfix
.reload /f advapi32.dll
```